# why cygwin add current project path as a prefix to cmake include path

Tags: c++, cmake, boost, cygwin, clion

After learning C++ recently, I faced a challenge while using Boost in a CMake project. I made some configurations in my CMakeLists.txt file and didn't receive any errors from CMake. However, I keep encountering an error stating that the 'boost/lexical_cast.hpp' file was not found when I include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp".

Here are some information that may be helpful to solve my problem.

I am using CLion 2023.3.3, and the toolchain is as follows.

[image]

And I add an option to CMake in order to find the Boost.

[image]

This is my CMakeLists.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(cpp_demo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Boost CONFIG REQUIRED)
if (NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Boost library not found")
endif ()
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message("Boost version " ${Boost_VERSION})
message(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(lexcast cpp-primer-plus/sample/chapter-18/lexcast.cpp)
#target_include_directories(lexcast PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

The CMake output is as follows.

```
Boost version 1.84.0
C:/Boost/include/boost-1_84
-- Configuring done (0.1s)
-- Generating done (1.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /cygdrive/d/CLionProjects/cpp_demo/cmake-build-debug
```

When I attempt to execute the code, the output indicates that it adds the current project's path before the value of the `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` macro.

```
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lexcast.dir/cpp-primer-plus/sample/chapter-18/lexcast.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/lexcast.dir/cpp-primer-plus/sample/chapter-18/lexcast.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/c++.exe  -I/cygdrive/d/CLionProjects/cpp_demo/C:/Boost/include/boost-1_84 -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT CMakeFiles/lexcast.dir/cpp-primer-plus/sample/chapter-18/lexcast.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/lexcast.dir/cpp-primer-plus/sample/chapter-18/lexcast.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/lexcast.dir/cpp-primer-plus/sample/chapter-18/lexcast.cpp.o -c /cygdrive/d/CLionProjects/cpp_demo/cpp-primer-plus/sample/chapter-18/lexcast.cpp
/cygdrive/d/CLionProjects/cpp_demo/cpp-primer-plus/sample/chapter-18/lexcast.cpp:6:10: fatal error: boost/lexical_cast.hpp: No such file or directory
    6 | #include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I don't know whether the problem is caused by CMake or Cygwin, and can anyone help me solve this problem.

I hope that I can include the Boost header file normally.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for your advice. I will edit the post latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do NOT use Clion, but it seems a classical case of mixing Cygwin and Windows PATH.

The last version of Cygwin Boost library is 1.66
https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libboost-devel/libboost-devel-1.66.0-1

Its header are located under `/usr/include/boost/` if you installed the package `libboost-devel`

so  the invocation of the compiler should have `-I/usr/include/boost`

CygWin CMAKE does not understand Windows PATH as `C:\` it expects POSIX path as `/usr/include/boost/`

Comment: Thank your for your solution. It did work. In fact, I tried to change the toolchain to MinGW before I saw your solution, it also did work. However I still wonder why Cygwin doesn't offer support like MinGW.

Comment: Which support ? Cygwin is POSIX oriented, a Linux-like mindset; Mingw uses some Cygwin assets but it is more Windows oriented. Depending on the scope you can choose what is better for you.